# Is the set $T$ of all sequences of rational numbers which converge to the number $3$ countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

> How many rational sequences exist for $\lim_{n\to 3}$

**My intuition:**

I believe the set $T$ is countable. It can be shown (in more ways than one) that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set. The set $T$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ and must therefore be countable.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: No, your intuition lies: In fact, $T\subset \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\dots$ (the set of rational sequences which is uncountable).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3080710/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for those great links! Unfortunately I am still a bit lost, and I would really like to understand this idea of using infinite binary string (which I cannot see mentioned in these links)

Answer (score 2):

$T$ has the continuum cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (Note that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ thus T is not countable).

Let us fix $(x_n)$ such that converges to $3$. Then, for every subsequence you take from $(x_n)$, converges again to $3$.
Thus if $A=\{B \subset \mathbb{N}: |B|=\aleph_0 \}$ you can define a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ where $n_k$ is an enumeration of $B \in A$ for every $B \in A$.

It is well known that $|A|=2^{\aleph_0}$ and thus for Cantor-Bernstein you can conclude $|T| \geq |A|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

To conclude just observe that $T \subset \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ and then $|T|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is a set of *sequences* of rationals, not a subset of rationals.

The number of such sequences is actually uncountable. Clearly $3$ is unimportant; let's just pick $0$. It's well known that the number of infinite binary sequences is uncountable, so let's say we have some infinite sequence $10110101...$ that starts with $1$.

Then the sequence
$$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{101}, \frac{1}{1011}, \frac{1}{10110} \cdots$$
converges to $0$. We can clearly pick uncountably many such sequences, and so $T$ is uncountable.

Comment: Your conclusion that $T$ is infininte is funny.

Comment: Ah, i meant uncountable, my bad.

Comment: Is this essentially a diagonalisation argument?

Comment: If you're referring to the proof that the number of infinite binary sequences is uncountable, then yes, this is a diagonalisation argument.

Alternatively, writing any real between $0.5$ and $1$ in binary gives an uncountable set of binary sequences.

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding the use of an infinite binary sequence. Do you have any resources or links on this topic?

Comment: An infinite binary sequence is really just a subset of the naturals (take $n$ to be in your set if and only if the digit in the $n^\text{th}$ place is $1$). This is then the power set of $\mathbb N$, which is uncountable by diagonalisation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument for more.

Comment: Thanks. I still am trying to understand your answer though. For instance, how do you knw that you can pick uncountably many such sequences?

Comment: I'm just taking the set of all such sequences, which is uncountable, and then making a unique sequence out of each one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to give a simple diagonalization argument that proves the statement directly.

Let's assume $T$ is countable, it's obviously infinite. So we can index all sequences $(x_n)$ in $T$ by an index $k$: $(x_n)_k$. Let's assume $n,k$ run through the positive integers, so start from $1$:

Now let's create a new sequence $(d_k)$ and define for all positive integers $k$:

$$
d_k = \begin{cases}
3,        & \text{ if }((x)_k)_k \neq 3, \\
3-\frac1k & \text{ if }((x)_k)_k = 3.
\end{cases}
$$

For any $k \ge 1$, $(d_n)$ is not the $k$-th sequence $(x_n)_k$ in $T$, because $d_k$ (the $k$-th element of $(d_n)$) was explicitely defined above to be different from the $k$-th element of $(x_n)_k$, which is $(x_k)_k$.

But obviously each $d_n$ is rational and $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_n=3$, so $(d_n)$ must be in T.

This is a contradiction and proves that $T$ is actually not countable.

Comment: Does $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$? Could you just also briefly elaborate on why $(d_n)$ is not in $T$.

Comment: @JulianAngussmith I added that $n,k$ are positive integers (I try to avoid the term "natural number" or $\mathbb N$ as some people think that includes $0$ and others think it excludes $0$). I also made the "$(d_n)$ not in $T$" part more detailed.